# Редактирование кода страницы в Элементор

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Есть WP с темой Astra, в Элементор (бесплатная версия), выполнена информационная страничка, в ней имеется кнопка, с помощью которой должна сработать всплывающее окно от сервиса рассылки для сбора подписчиков.
Чтобы так сработало - необходимо вставить в вышеуказанную страницу код пикселя от сервиса.
Но не могу найти, куда вставить.
Вставка кода пикселя через редактор темы - не помогает, надо вставить именно в код конкретной странички.